# How can we replace this typedef with "using"?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using the following line of code to create a typedef for a void function pointer.

```
typedef void(*MyFuncT) (void);
```

I want to replace it and use `using` instead. But, I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an *alias-declaration* the right hand side should be a *type-id*. You can get the *type-id* by removing the identifier from the declaration of a single entity. You would of course put this on the left hand side.

```
using MyFuncT = void (*)(void);
```

Comment: Answer was very fast and I need to wait 5 mins to accep it.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
using MyFuncT = void(*)(void)
```